# xml to xml transformation for repeating tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I am newbie to write XSL.I am familiar with working on XML using the DOM parser 10 years ago, but the technologies changed. I guess I can still get this done with Java DOM parsers but it will be overhead to the systems.

I have a source XML in below format. the tag 'Value' occurrences are variable. I need to transform this to second xml format.

**XML Source:**

```
  <Part>
     <PartNumber>XYZ</PartNumber>
     <ProductLines>
        <Value>P58</Value>
        <Value>P84</Value>
        <Value>P88</Value>
        <Value>P99</Value>
     </ProductLines>
    </Part>
```

**XML Target To**

```
    <Part>
     <PartNumber>XYZ</PartNumber>
     <ProductLines>P58,P84,P88,P99</ProductLines>
    </Part>
```

I am trying with below XSL, not working: Need advice from the XML gurus.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
        version="1.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="ProductLines">
            <xsl:for-each select="Value">
                <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="ProductLines/node()"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: what's 'not working'? can you elaborate specific problem? That usually helps to get you closer to a solution anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this to concatenate the values:

```
<xsl:variable name="concatenated_value">
    <xsl:for-each select="Value">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect.